# loshon hora and shul

Tags: sources-mekorot, synagogue, lashon-hara-slander

I heard that speaking *Loshon Hora, Rechilus* or to have *arguments* and *quarreling* is a serious crime in itself. It becomes an even greater sin when spoken in a *shul* or *yeshiva*, for the person, which demonstrates a greater disregard for the honor of the *Shechinah*. A traitorous act performed in the king’s palace is a greater crime than if done elsewhere.]

Where in *halachah* does it say this?

Comment: This question would be much stronger if you'd attribute where you heard this concept.

Comment: The answer below, addresses the "honor of the shul", in a sense. Regardless, the shul or Bet Midrash is a public place - a holy one, at that. Not only are you dispersing lashon hara to a group of people at one time, which is extremely serious in ANY public place, but, consider that you shouldn't be chattering about ANY non-relevant subject in a shul or Bet Midrash, how much more worse is it that what you talk about is lashon hara!

Answer (score 4):

One source can be found in [Sefer Chafetz Chayim](http://www.chafetzchayim.org/index.php/component/content/article/18-sefer-chafetz-chayim-read-online), in the introduction, where he lists positive commandments that one may transgress when speaking Lashon Hara (Sif Zayin, pages 70-71 of Volume 1 in the link).

In a nutshell, one violates the prohibition of וּמִקְדָּשִׁי תִּירָאוּ - revere My sanctuaries (Vayikra 19:30).

I just want to clarify, this prohibition of וּמִקְדָּשִׁי תִּירָאוּ seems to be a separate prohibition in its own right (i.e. it's not an extension of Loshon Hora, but an additional prohibition that one can violate). The Chafetz Chayim included it in his Sefer to show which additional prohibitions one could violate when speaking Lashon Hora. However, one can violate the prohibition in a myriad of ways (even when the action itself might not be a prohibition on its own).